# OOM although very small network

Tags: tensorflow

Operating System:
Ubuntu 16.04

Installed version of CUDA and cuDNN: 
CUDA 8.0
CuDNN 5.1

TensorFlow v0.12.1

Hi,
I'm getting an OOM message on a very small network, and running on 2 GTX 1080.
It's a 2 layer network, first 2 layers of VGG, conv1_1, conv1_2.
The input image is 400x400 and I am trying to run a batch of size 16.

My training is taking a feature vector from 4 spatial positions and training with some loss on it.
So for example, after 2 VGG conv layers I will have a feature vector of size 64 at each pixel, or to be exact, a tensor of size [16,400,400,64].
I want to take these vectors from 4 locations, meaning I will have 4 vectors of length 64, then calculating some loss function on them.

So this is my inference function:

```
def inference(images, x1, y, x2, z, train=False):
  # conv1_1
  with tf.variable_scope('conv1_1') as scope:
    kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[3, 3, 3, 64], wd=0.000, layer_name=scope.name)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(images, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [64], tf.constant_initializer(0.0), layer_name=scope.name)
    conv1_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases), name=scope.name)

  # conv1_2
  with tf.variable_scope('conv1_2') as scope:
    kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[3, 3, 64, 64], wd=0.000, layer_name=scope.name)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(conv1_1, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [64], tf.constant_initializer(0.0), layer_name=scope.name)
    conv1_2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases), name=scope.name)

  in1=tf.reshape(conv1_2[0, x1[0][0], x1[0][1], :],[1,64])
  in2=tf.reshape(conv1_2[0, y[0][0], y[0][1], :],[1,64])
  in3=tf.reshape(conv1_2[0, x2[0][0], x2[0][1], :],[1,64])
  in4=tf.reshape(conv1_2[0, z[0][0], z[0][1], :],[1,64])

  for i in range (1, FLAGS.batch_size):
      in1 = tf.concat(0,[in1,tf.reshape(conv1_2[i, x1[i][0], x1[i][1], :],[1,64])])
      in2 = tf.concat(0,[in2,tf.reshape(conv1_2[i, y[i][0], y[i][1], :],[1,64])])
      in3 = tf.concat(0,[in3,tf.reshape(conv1_2[i, x2[i][0], x2[i][1], :],[1,64])])
      in4 = tf.concat(0,[in4,tf.reshape(conv1_2[i, z[i][0], z[i][1], :],[1,64])])
```

Now, each in1,in2,in3,in4 is of size [16,64]
From here on I calculate some loss with that.
For some reason I am getting an OOM message, although this is a very small network. **I guess that the way I am taking these feature vectors makes the tool allocate way bigger memory than needed.**

> ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating
>   tensor with shape[16,400,400,64]   [[Node:
>   gradients/strided_slice_84_grad/StridedSliceGrad =
>   StridedSliceGrad[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT, begin_mask=8,
>   ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=8, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=7,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](gradients/strided_slice_84_grad/Shape,
>   strided_slice_84/stack, strided_slice_84/stack_1,
>   strided_slice_84/stack_2, gradients/Reshape_16_grad/Reshape)]]
>   [[Node: gradients/conv1_1/BiasAdd_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1/_99
>   = _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1,
>   tensor_name="edge_2359_gradients/conv1_1/BiasAdd_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1",
>   tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: How many images are you using? If it's a lot of images even a small network can quickly get memory issues.

Comment: 16 images. Shouldn't be the problem.
I think the way I am taking these feature vector makes TensorFlow allocate way more memory than needed

Comment: You could try smaller images and decreasing the batchsize.  I think that last tf.concat is what is messing you up.  If you freeze the graph before running this you can also see if tensorflow is creating any new nodes at runtime.